# Step counter not working on Samsung phones which dont have Step sensors

Tags: java, android, kotlin, activity-recognition

i am developing simple step counter app
app works on almost devices but problem is app not working on some Samsung phones and other phone
which don't have step counter sensor. I don't want to use Google FIT
I Have Activity Recognition permission accepted still step counter not working

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />`

Phone model :**Galaxy A7 2018 | SM-A750GZBJTPA**

its not working because this model **don't have
STEP_COUNTER AND STEP_DETECTOR sensor.**

other apps from markets are working, i don't know how they implemented that functionality

i am trying to implement through accelerometer sensor but application stop counting sensors
when phone is in DOZE MODE,
anyone suggest how to implement?

Comment: I also got this error recently.

Comment: @ThanhTung i used accelerator to count steps in background. It is condition based if phone have step counter sensor then use it else use accelerameter sensor. even app is closed, It's is very bad practice to hold wake lock, but i have no choice so i hold wake lock and detected high peak to measure step all time. disadvantage is huge battery consumption.